# can i detect DOM insertions using yepnope/modernizer.load()

Tags: jquery, modernizr, yepnope

In a windows forms application we have a Master.js file which is referenced after loading modernizr.

I'm declaring my modernizer.load tests in a $(document).ready function at the bottom of the masterpage.js and it caters for loading my js files based on the tests I require.

i.e.

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        Modernizr.addTest('mytest', $('section #myid').length > 0);    
        Modernizr.load({
            test: Modernizr.mytest,
            yep: ["custom1.js",
                "customjs2.js"],
            complete: {
                //do stuff
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

However i would like this test to be done both on document.ready and potentially at DOM insertion points which may occur after this. Is this possible with Modernizr or jQuery?

My goal is to declare all modernizr tests in my masterpage.js rather than redeclaring the tests after potential future points when i may insert DOM elements which require the resources to loaded in the tests.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `Modernizr.addTest()` isn't really necessary in your case (it'll latch and probably cause undesirable behaviour). You could simply do:

```
Modernizr.load({
    test: $('section #myid').length > 0,
    ...
});
```

Although you can probably skip that altogether, depending on how you monitor the DOM. **[Livequery](https://github.com/brandonaaron/livequery)** is good for this:

```
$('section #myid').livequery(function () {
    // This will run whenever a new element matches the selector: either now
    // (if the element already exists), or when it's inserted into the DOM later
    Modernizr.load({
        // no test needed - just use it as an async loader
        load: ['custom1.js', 'custom2.js'],
        complete: function () {
            // do stuff
        }
    });

    // Presumably you only want the above to run once, so remove the Livequery
    // handler now (`arguments.callee` is the current function, i.e. the event
    // handler)
    $('section #myid').expire(arguments.callee);
});
```

Comment: Oh, and `$('#myid')` would be slightly faster. If you only want to perform the action if `#myid` is loaded as a descendant of a `<section>` element, it'd be more readable to test that condition inside the livequery function.

Comment: cheers Stu,This seems to be the best option thus far, although it appears(looking at the source) to basically run the queries every 20 miliseconds. So rather than responding to a dom insertion event(which appears not to exist), it basically checks until the selector is true.

Comment: You could consider [Mutation Observers](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/02/Detect-DOM-changes-with-Mutation-Observers) - a new feature in some browsers which can monitor the DOM without continually querying - and fall back to Livequery if they're not available? Here's how to detect support: https://gist.github.com/stucox/5231211